# Angular - Reference scope variable in directive without $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display the first image in an array that is fed into my directive, however, I do not understand why this doesn't work. Can you please explain?

Script.js file:

```
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('MyController', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.imageList=[
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Polar_Bear_AdF.jpg',
    'http://www.polarbearsinternational.org/sites/default/files/styles/media_full/public/00473-10104_0.jpg?itok=uv9Mr5rz',
    'http://www.polarbearsinternational.org/sites/default/files/styles/inside_full/public/sca-000005.jpg?itok=7HybQm2o'
  ];
})

.directive('myImageGallery', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      images: '='
    },
    controller: function() {
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<ul><img images="vm.images" ng-src={{ vm.images[0] }}</li></ul>'
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <my-image-gallery images="myCtrl.imageList"></my-image-gallery>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to correct your template to:

```
template: '<ul><li><img ng-src="{{images[0]}}"></li></ul>'
```

You're missing the quotes `" "` around the ng-src attribute, and you can just access the directive's isolate $scope directly with `images[0]`. Your img tag is also missing the closing bracket `>`.

This is how you can access `images` within the `vm` controller:

```
scope:{
  images: '='
},
controller: function($scope) {
  this.images = $scope.images;
},
controllerAs: 'vm',
template: '<ul><li><img ng-src="{{vm.images[0]}}"></li></ul>'
```

You can use `bindToController` to automatically bind the directive's isolate scope to the controller. Just make sure you do have the controller property present or it will throw an error.

```
.directive('myImageGallery', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      images: '='
    },
    controller: function() {},
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '<ul><li><img ng-src="{{vm.images[0]}}"</li></ul>'
  };
});
```

Comment: @nweg Thanks. Updated.

Comment: I would use `bindToController: true` instead of using `this.images = $scope.images`.

Comment: Thanks guys! And yes, bindToController was the missing magic as well. Found a cool article here: http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/